# Centred Moving Average

Tags: time-series, analysis

I'm trying to retrieve the trend component from NDVI (MODIS) time series using the 4 centred moving average in excel, my problem is the time series has some holes in it (missing dates) [image: Table]
I want to know if that's going to create a problem in the resulting trend? If yes, please help me if you know a substitute method I can use with this kind of data

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a spatial question and EXCEL is a horrible place to perform this type of analysis. What you are looking for is an imputation of missing values. Commonly, for timeseries data, this is done using something like a LOESS (locally weighted smoothing) regression, some type of Spline fit or Savitzky-Golay kernel smoothing. This conceptually creates a nonlinear trend line for the data and, through estimation, fills missing data following the fit trend. I have no idea if this is even possible in EXCEL but, at least it is a place to start. Here is a [link that implements LOESS regression](https://peltiertech.com/loess-smoothing-in-excel/) in EXCEL but, how you would estimate missing values is the looming question. This is why folks use statistical software!

If you move this analysis to Python or R there becomes numerous avenues to peruse including what you do with the resulting timeseries. Pulling a trend from a linear regression is not a prudent approach (particularity with NDVI) as periodicity (seasonal effects) comes into play and adds considerable bias to your resulting trend, thus invalidating results and inference. Following common timeseries processing workflows you would, 1) impute missing values, 2) smooth your timeseries to remove outlier effects, 3) decompose the timeseries to separate out the trend, seasonal, and noise components, 4) derive trend from the trend component. I would be happy to provide code for this in R but, would also encourage you to post this question on a different forum that is not focused on spatial analysis or, rephrase your question to emphasis the spatial component.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I'm actually new to this field so I don't know much of methods and softwares, and I would be very grateful if you could help me with the code.